# Why can I not create a multi-line UILabel with Auto Layout? Something always is off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, autolayout

I want to have a two-line UILabel at the bottom of my UITextFields, acting as a disclaimer.

I have the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    UILabel *InstapaperSubscriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.text = @"Requires an Instapaper subscription, please see the Instapaper website for more details.";
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40;
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:112/255.0 green:112/255.0 blue:111/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    InstapaperSubscriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    [self.view addSubview:InstapaperSubscriptionLabel];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:InstapaperSubscriptionLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.passwordBox
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:15.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:InstapaperSubscriptionLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:20.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:InstapaperSubscriptionLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:20.0]];
```

But each time I load the view, it looks like this:

[image]

Where it goes off the side of the screen. Why is it doing this? I want it more centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the constant for the last constraint you show in your question should be -20, not 20.
What you're saying with that code is:

label trailing = superview right * 1 + 20 which will put the trailing edge of the label 20 points off the screen to the right.